# Aloha Editor: Add new styles to the toolbar and content

Tags: javascript, css, aloha-editor

How to add the custom styles to the aloha editor.

I have a block of text...to that text i would like to add some background color and extra markup to the block of text.

for eg.

```
ddhjhdhs ahdksahd hkjdhasjhdkjh hdjkhsakj hdjshd shj hdjsahdkja hdkjshdkjh hkjhsakjdhakjh
dsadak dhksadkaj lkdjakl jslkajdl
```

consider this is a block of text it is having some bg color...Like this i would like to add custome styles to aloha editor.pls explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Aloha [sidebar](http://aloha-editor.org/guides/sidebar.html) makes possible to define a css class on the selected block of text.

You may also be interested by this color-selector 3rd-party plugin : https://github.com/deliminator/Aloha-Plugin-Colorselector

If it doesn't fit your needs, you will have to write your own plugin.

I hope it helps